# Dividing DateTime by custom increment down to seconds

Tags: c#, list, datetime, reporting, timespan

Small challenge. Can't seem to figure it out.

If I have a count of 30 "sections" and I want to divide any two (start and end) dates by that value, how would I do this?

```
var sections = 30;
var start = new DateTime("2014-06-17T18:17:00.772Z");
var end = new DateTime("2014-06-17T19:10:29.123Z");
var dateRange = new List<DateTime>();

for(int i = 0; i < sections; i++)
{
// What! dateRange.Add( new DateTime(...) );
}
```

Essentially, I need 30 points of data.

But it gets complicated when I start passing just "seconds or minutes of time" as the start and end date.

So how do I always capture dates in the specified section count?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Erik

Comment: You have end date less than start date ?

Comment: No, not 30 days. 30 increments. So that it satisfies a start and end date that is only a couple minutes (or hours, or seconds, or mileseconds) apart.

Comment: Can you put the exact dates in your question, *compilable* and also what exactly you need as an output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the start and end time to "bookend" the sections, which means you need to calculate the interval based on `N-1` segments .  Here's a one-liner using Linq:

```
var sections = 30;
var start = DateTime.Parse("2014-06-17T18:17:00.772");
var end = DateTime.Parse("2014-06-17T19:10:29.123");

var dateRange = Enumerable.Range(0,sections)
                          .Select(i => start.AddTicks((end-start).Ticks/(sections-1) * i));
```

yields:

```
2014-06-17 18:17:00Z 
2014-06-17 18:18:51Z 
2014-06-17 18:20:42Z 
2014-06-17 18:22:32Z 
2014-06-17 18:24:23Z 
2014-06-17 18:26:13Z 
2014-06-17 18:28:04Z 
2014-06-17 18:29:55Z 
2014-06-17 18:31:45Z 
2014-06-17 18:33:36Z 
2014-06-17 18:35:27Z 
2014-06-17 18:37:17Z 
2014-06-17 18:39:08Z 
2014-06-17 18:40:58Z 
2014-06-17 18:42:49Z 
2014-06-17 18:44:40Z 
2014-06-17 18:46:30Z 
2014-06-17 18:48:21Z 
2014-06-17 18:50:12Z 
2014-06-17 18:52:02Z 
2014-06-17 18:53:53Z 
2014-06-17 18:55:44Z 
2014-06-17 18:57:34Z 
2014-06-17 18:59:25Z 
2014-06-17 19:01:15Z 
2014-06-17 19:03:06Z 
2014-06-17 19:04:57Z 
2014-06-17 19:06:47Z 
2014-06-17 19:08:38Z 
2014-06-17 19:10:29Z
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoud be able to do it like this:

```
var sections = 30;
var start = new DateTime(2015,12, 1);
var end = new DateTime(2016, 3, 1);
var dateRange = new List<DateTime>();

var difference = (end - start).TotalMilliseconds;  //difference in milliseconds
var oneSection = difference/sections;    //length on one section in milliseconds
var tempDate = start;
for (int i = 0; i < sections - 1; i++)   //add one section less
{
    tempDate = tempDate.AddMilliseconds(oneSection);
    dateRange.Add(tempDate);
}
dateRange.Add(end);   //add end as last section
```

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the difference between start and end dates. Get the difference in total seconds, divide it by `seciotns` *(30)*, that will give you the increment you need in `start` date. Later you can use a loop and fill your `dateRange` like:

```
var sections = 30;
var start = new DateTime(2015,1,1);
var end = new DateTime(2015,3,1);
var totalDays = Math.Abs((end - start).TotalSeconds);
var increment = totalDays / sections;
var dateRange = new List<DateTime>();
for (int i = 0; i < sections; i++)
{
    start = start.AddSeconds(increment);
    dateRange.Add(start);
}
```

The last item in your list, will not exactly be the `end` date. If you want to include `end` as the last item in your list then do that explicitly like:

```
dateRange[dateRange.Count - 1] = end;
```